# How to change background color of container when it tapped

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to change color of container in this way ->

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color _color = Colors.amber;

    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          _color = Colors.deepPurple;
          print('clicked');
        },
        child: SizedBox.expand(
          child: Container(
            color: _color,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'HELLo THERE',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontFamily: 'Starjedi'
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It prints the string 'clicked' but don't change a color.

So, how can I do that in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert your widget to `StatefulWidget`.
2. Use `setState` callback.
3. Declare variable at class level (outside build)

Full solution:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget { // use this
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Color _color = Colors.amber; // declare it here

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() { // use setState
            _color = Colors.deepPurple;
          });
          print('clicked');
        },
        child: SizedBox.expand(
          child: Container(
            color: _color,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'HELLo THERE',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontFamily: 'Starjedi'
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `StatelessWidget` you need to use a `StatefulWidget` and call the method `setState` in your `onTap` property. Moreover you set the value of `_color` in the build method which means that it'll always be reset to `Colors.amber` when you refresh the state of your screen, you need to move `_color` outside of `build`.

**Code Sample:**

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() => _color = Colors.deepPurple);
        print('clicked');
      },
      child: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Container(
          color: _color,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'HELLo THERE',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: 'Starjedi',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}​
```